# Перенос строк в PhpStorm. Уменьшение длины строк кода

Tags: html, phpstorm, редактор, настройки, редактор-текста

Скачал страницу https://www.hola.com/us-es/salud-y-belleza/20211125305386/adamari-lopez-sacrificio-dieta/ и открыл её PhpStorm. В результате получил окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0089)https://www.hola.com/us-es/salud-y-belleza/20211125305386/adamari-lopez-sacrificio-dieta/ -->
<html lang="es-US" data-template="short_news">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- header UserCountryCode: no UserCountryCode header -->
  <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, user-scalable=yes">
  <meta name="last_mod" content="Thu, 25 Nov 2021 21:51:41 GMT">
  <title>Adamari López y su sacrificio más grande para perder peso</title>
  <link rel="preload" as="image" href="./AdamariLopez_files/adamari-l-pez.jpg" media="(max-width: 639px)">
  <link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://images.hola.com/us/images/026e-136e42f3f8fa-16e0a380d3e9-1000/horizontal-800/adamari-l-pez.jpg" media="(min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)">
  <link rel="preload" as="image" href="https://images.hola.com/us/images/026e-136e42f3f8fa-16e0a380d3e9-1000/horizontal-1200/adamari-l-pez.jpg" media="(min-width: 1024px)">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://use.typekit.net/" crossorigin="">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://images.hola.com/">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin="">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://use.typekit.net/">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://images.hola.com/">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://sdk.privacy-center.org/">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://www.googletagservices.com/">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://www.google-analytics.com/">
```

Каким образом разбить строки, изображенные на скриншоте, на несколько строк? (так чтобы было как на участке кода, приведенном выше)? Нужно уменьшить ширину строк.

Comment: Code->Reformat code (Ctrl+Alt+L)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov cпасибо помогло.